# How to deal with the edge weight in the graph in minizinc?

Tags: solver, gurobi, minizinc

I have a task like the follow figure:

[image]

I need code a optimization model in Minizinc to solver placement problem, that is, solve give a *placement* strategy to indicate which *Host* should *a, b, c* to place.

One of the chanllenge that I faced is the constraint that the resource requirement do not exceed the resource.

I did it like:

```
int: numHosts = 5;
set of int: hosts = 1..numHosts;

int: numRel = 2;
set of int: relindx = 1..numRel;
array[relindx] of int: preNode = [1, 1];    % edge (1, 2), (2, 3) a=1, b=2, c=3
array[relindx] of int: postNode = [2, 3];

int: sliceLen = 3;
set of int: sSlice = 1..sliceLen;
array[sSlice] of int: slice = [1, 2, 3];  % a, b, c

int: numVnfs = 5;  % types of rectangle(a, b, c, d, e)
set of int: vnfs = 1..numVnfs;
array[vnfs, vnfs] of int: bandwidth_resource = array2d(1..numHosts, 1..numHosts, [0,0,30,0,0, 0,0,35,0,30, 30,35,0,0,40, 0,0,0,0,35, 0,30,40,35,0]); % array2d save the edge resources
array[vnfs, vnfs] of int: vnf_bandwidth = array2d(1..numVnfs, 1..numVnfs, [0,2,2,4,4, 2,0,3,4,2, 2,3,0,4,3, 4,4,4,0,2, 4,2,3,2,0]); % array2d save the source requirement of rectangle

% DECISION VARIABLES
array[sSlice] of var hosts: placement;
array[vnfs, vnfs] of var int: bandwidth_used;

% CONSTRAINTS
constraint forall(host1 in hosts, host2 in hosts)
(
  bandwidth_used[host1, host2] = sum(c1 in preNode, c2 in postNode where placement[c1] = host1 /\ placement[c2] = host2) (vnf_bandwidth[c1, c2])
);

constraint forall(vnf in vnfs)
(
    bandwidth_used[vnf, vnf] <= bandwidth_resource[vnf, vnf]
);
```

Now, the **First** question is solver can give a plecement but ***bandwidth_used*** connot calculate coorectly.

the **second** question is how to ***sum*** the resource used that host do not conected directly

For example, in the figure rectangle **a** placed on **Host1** and rectangle **b** placed on **Host2**, so the *bandwidth_used* should calculate the resource used in both edge ***(Host1, Host3)*** and edge ***(Host2, Host3)***.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your problem is a mapping problem with communication constraints on bandwidth. Communication between two tasks mapped into two hosts can, in fact, be routed in different ways. You propose (Host1, Host3) and (Host3, Host2) but it can also be routed (Host1, Host3), (Host3, Host5) and (Host5, Host2). This can be modelled by network flow constraints (one constraint for each communication). For more details you can check our minizinc model in https://github.com/MiniZinc/minizinc-benchmarks/tree/master/mapping.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Krzysztof, but I'm just a rookie in Minizinc. So, The model in your answer is a bit diffcult to understand to me. Could you please give me a simpler and easier to unstand example? I'm sorry, but I'm really really such a rubbish(555) .